# fetch request returning null after code removed that inserts data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In the code below (in ViewDidLoad), I import a JSON file into an iOS project, and then persist the data using Core Data and, at the end, perform a fetch request successfully. However, after I remove the code that imports the file and persists the data, the fetch request starts returning `(null)`. Based on the code below, can you explain why this is happening?

```
   id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];


    NSError* err = nil;
    NSString* dataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"inventorydata" ofType:@"json"];
    NSArray* inventoryData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath]
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&err];
    if(err) NSLog(@"Error %@",[err description]);
    NSLog(@"Imported Data: %@", inventoryData);

    [Questions enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        Inventory *partsInfo= [NSEntityDescription
                                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Inventory"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        partsInfo.name = [obj objectForKey:@"name"];
        partsInfo.sku = [obj objectForKey:@"sku"];



        Supplier *supplierInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Supplier"
                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        supplierInfo.supplierId = [obj objectForKey:@"supplierId"];
        [supplierInfo setValue:[NSSet setWithObject:partsInfo ] forKey:@"partData"];


    }];
    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Supplier"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    self.fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (Supplier *info in self.fetchedObjects) {
        NSLog(@"supplierId: %@", info.supplierId);

    }
```

Comment: Are you saying `[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]` is returning `nil`? If so what does `error` hold after that call?

Comment: @Rich, I'm saying that, once I delete all the code that inserts the objects, the fetch no longer works. When I log the self.fetchedObjects after it's empty. The first answer below indicates I need to saveContext (I thought CoreData saved automatically) but the [delegate saveContext] method is throwing an error when I add it as explained in comment to that answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
   [Questions enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    Inventory *partsInfo= [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Inventory"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    partsInfo.name = [obj objectForKey:@"name"];
    partsInfo.sku = [obj objectForKey:@"sku"];



    Supplier *supplierInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Supplier"
                      inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    supplierInfo.supplierId = [obj objectForKey:@"supplierId"];
    [supplierInfo setValue:[NSSet setWithObject:partsInfo ] forKey:@"partData"];
    }];

   //Add this code : need to save database. 
   [delegate saveContext];

    // You should add this method in AppDelegate.m
    - (void)saveContext{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
    if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
         // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
         // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    } 
    }  
    }
```

Comment: when I add that it's saying, "no known instance method for selector saveContext", however the appDelegate file does have a method - (void)saveContext;

Comment: @Leahcim make sure that method (`saveContext`) is also in the app delegates header

Comment: @Rich it is, do you see anything wrong with this code `id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];`

Comment: I think you add core data by band. If you use default, it will create by itself. But no problem, just add saveContext function to appDelegate file.

Comment: it worked when I called save like this ` NSError *error;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
     NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }`

Comment: OK. Just need save data to database